# Longest Prefix matching with REDIS having over 5 million key-value pairs

Tags: c, linux, redis

I've over 5 million key-value pairs stored in REDIS server. Incoming key, which we need to search in REDIS server will be like "**key_num_id**" format.

Keys and values are stored in the REDIS server like "**key_pfx_id**" format. All keys will be unique key (No two keys would be same). Below are few examples:

```
key_1234_11
key_123_12
key_123_11
key_12_11
..
..
```

where 1234, 123, 12 are the prefix of **num** in incoming key **key_num_id**.

Now, for example if we get **key_1234567890_11** as the incoming key then REDIS should give **value** corresponding to **"key_1234_11"** which is the best match for the **"num"** we got in incoming key **"1234567890"** in our example.

One way is to do this is query the REDIS server multiple times till we got the value; e.g.

```
GET key_1234567890_11
GET key_123456789_11
GET key_12345678_11
GET key_1234567_11
.
.
```

But I think this is the costly solution as I'm getting around 2000 incoming keys in a second. So want to have optimized solution. Can anyone help in this as I'm newbie in REDIS

**NOTE: I'm doing all above in C code**

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this in a single call to Redis is put the iteration logic in a Lua script.

```
local input = KEYS[1]
local key, output
while string.len(input) > 1 do
  key = "test_" .. input .. "_11"
  output = redis.call("GET", key)
  if output then return output end
  input = string.sub(input, 1, string.len(input) - 1)
end
return nil
```

When called (`redis.eval(script_body, ["12345678"])`) it should correctly return the value of `key_1234_11`. This is a trivial example, obviously, and will need to be further tailored for your application.

This saves you the overhead of making many calls to redis, but, I guess compared to C then Lua itself might be a bit of an overhead. I can't be certain a Lua script is faster in this scenario, but it may be.